# Javascript - Determine browser from drop event data

Tags: javascript, drag-and-drop

I am trying to implement cross browser drag and drop, and wanted to know if there is a way to determine the browser type from the drop event data transfer data.

Specifically, I am trying to determine if the drag originated from Chrome when the drop occurs in Safari. I have looked at the `event.view.navigator.userAgent` and `event.originalEvent.view.navigator.userAgent` and both return a string corresponding to Safari and not Chrome.

Any ideas here would be very helpful.